# How to write multiple rows from a list into a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv

I already was able to implement part 1. and not able to do part 2 for the following:

1. Processed Inventory Reports:
   a. FullInventory.csv -- all the items listed by row with all their information . .
   The items should be sorted alphabetically by manufacturer. Each row should contain item ID,
   manufacturer name, item type, price, service date, and list if it is damaged.
   The item attributes must appear in this order.
   b. Item type Inventory list, i.e LaptopInventory.csv -- there should be a file for each item
   type and the item type needs to be in the file name. Each row of the file should contain
   item ID, manufacturer name, price, service date, and list if it is damaged. The items
   should be sorted by their item ID.

   ```
    for i in range(len(csv_content)):
        file_name = csv_content[i][2]
        for j in range(i+1 , len(csv_content)):
            if 'laptop' == csv_content[j][2]:
                    with open(file_name + '.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
                        writer = csv.writer(file)
                        writer.writerow(csv_content)
   ```

Comment: try to read this file using pandas. pandas save csv file in dataframe formate where you can change sort and change order of columns easily. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to ur question?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

```
import csv

ls = [['Name'], ['name1'], ['name2'], ['name3']]
f = open('sample.csv', 'w+', newline ='')

with f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerows(ls)
```

Comment: I am trying to reach ls = [['Name'], ['name1'], ['name2'], ['name3']] from a csv file with different list names that match specific element in a list.. I can't use panda or lambda